# Close busy form when background-worker is complete?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have an application that when busy will open a busy form (FormWaitingForm) to indicate to the user that the application is busy. How do i close FormWaitingForm in the event backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompletedbelow ?

```
private void radButtonCheckFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

                    // define the event handlers
                    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(ProcessTickTemp);

                    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

                    bw.RunWorkerAsync(); // starts the background worker

                    // execution continues here in parallel to the background worker


                    using (var FormWaitingForm = new WaitingForm()) //  
                    {
                        var result = FormWaitingForm.ShowDialog();

                    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
             // How do i close FormWaitingForm here ?
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this. Retain a reference to the form outside of the click method and then open it non-modally (so that you don't have to wait for the user to close it).

```
WaitingForm formWaitingForm;

private void radButtonCheckFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // background code here

    formWaitingForm = new WaitingForm();
    formWaitingForm.Show();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    formWaitingForm.Close();
    formWaitingForm.Dispose();
}
```

You would have to add some code to handle if the user closes the waiting form without waiting for you to do it.

That said, the way I usually implement a waiting/progress-type form is to incorporate the background process into the progress form itself and show something like a progress bar.

[This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160219/ProgressForm-A-simple-form-linked-to-a-BackgroundW) might give you some more ideas.